# Do i need to pay Tax in India as well?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, united-kingdom, india, dtaa

I am an Indian and working in India for a software company. I was transferred to UK branch of my software company to work on an assignment at client site.

- I reached UK on 31 July 2015 on 9 months Work permit.
- Started to work with client company, got salary in UK for August(Full
  month salary)/September(Full month salary)/October(20 days salary).
- After 20 October I had to come to India as my assignment was complete
  and now I am working in my parent company which sent me for
  assignment in UK.
- I have UK National Insurance number and the tax was deducted from my
  salary I earned in UK.
- I did not bring any money(Pounds) with me to India as I spent max
  money up there.

Question:
Does the income earned in UK add to my income earned in India for this financial year(2015-16) and do i have to pay tax here(India) again despite I paid tax in UK? Please Advise.

Answer (score 2):

As you have spent more than 182 days in India you are considered as resident for tax purposes. You have to pay taxes on your global income. India and UK have dual tax avoidance agreement and you can claim relief to the extent taxes paid in UK.